# how to append char at start and end of each element in scala seq?

Tags: scala

I am trying some string manipulation on sequence

I have sequence of elements ex: Seq("aaa","bbb","ccc") and need to be converted to String with appending some characters to start and end of each element

result should be string -> "aaa","bbb","ccc"

```scala
scala> val initial = Seq("aaa","bbb","ccc")

initial: Seq[String] = List(aaa, bbb, ccc)

scala> initial.foldLeft(Seq [String] ()){(z,x)=>z:+("\""+x+"\""+",")}

res2: Seq[String] = List("aaa",, "bbb",, "ccc",)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not see you adding any character at all. Additionally, what have you tried? Which problems do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to do this:

```
def appndAndPrependTo[A](data: Seq[A])(s: String): Seq[String] =
  data.map(a => s"${s}${a}${s}")
```

Comment: I think OP also wants to concatenate all the strings with a separator, so this + `mkString(",")`

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved using only `mkString(start, sep, end)`

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#mkString(start:String,sep:String,end:String):String

```scala
List("aaa", "bbb", "ccc").mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a foldLeft to transform elements.

Try this

`initial.map(x=> s""""${x}"""").mkString(",")`

Comment: doesn't look pretty with the tripple quotes but hey, can't escape in interpolation so what are you going to do